# SQLAlchemy inheritance based on whether data exists in another table

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I have two legacy table that I would like to use SQLAlchemy declarative to access data.

```
Order:
order_id
is_processed

FooData:
foo_id
order_id
```

A order may or may not have FooData and I would like to distinguish between the two order types using SQLAlchemy declarative models.

The problem I have wrapping my head around is.

- How do I set up such a relationship? Ideally I'd have two classes Order and FooOrder where Order has no FooData and FooOrder has FooData.
- I have to query both types (Order and FooOrder) together based on is_processed and process them differently based on whether it is Order or FooOrder. How do I go about querying in this case?

Comment: Do you only need to query this data (for reporting etc) or also need to support other operations (insert, update, ..)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the DB, then simply add one [discriminator column](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance), set
the value of this column to proper value (order|foodata) depending on whether
the foodata exists for it, make it `NOT NULL` and configure simple Joined Table Inheritance.

If you cannot change the DB (add a discriminator column) and you only have the simple
2-table model as you show, then I would not use inheritance, but rather 1-1 relationship.

**Model Definition:**

```
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

class FooData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo_data'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
    # @note: you need next line only if your DB does not have FK defined
    #__table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(['order_id'], ['order.order_id']), {'autoload': True})

# define 1-[0..1] relationship from Order to FooData with eager loading
Order.foodata = relationship(FooData, uselist=False, lazy="joined", backref="order")
```

**Adding new objects:**

```
ord = Order(); ord.is_processed = False
session.add(ord)
ord = Order(); ord.is_processed = False
foo = FooData(); foo.someinfo = "test foo created from SA"
ord.foodata = foo
session.add(ord)
session.commit()
```

**Query: all based on is_processed:**

```
qry = session.query(Order).filter(Order.is_processed == False)
for ord in qry:
    print ord, ord.foodata
```

***A la*** Polymorphism:

You can even implement methods on your `Order` and `FooData` in a way that it
would seem they are in fact using inheritance:

```
class Order(Base):
    # ...
    def process_order(self):
        if self.foodata:
            self.foodata.process_order()
        else:
            print "processing order: ", self

class FooData(Base):
    # ...
    def process_order(self):
        print "processing foo_data: ", self
```

Comment: So discriminator has to be a column and can't be something computed on the fly?

Comment: Exactly. Although you can find text like `While there are some “tricks” to work around the requirement that there be a discriminator column...` in here (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=discriminator#joined-table-inheritance), I was not able to find work-arounds. It would be fantastic if Mike [http://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek] could comment on this.